# CSS3 Transition different depending on search or text input?

Tags: html, forms, css, css-transitions

First off, I went and looked at the responses generated for answers when asking this question. Didn't find anything similar. I'm just dealing with a weird quirk in my code pen. A result I was not expecting.

The easiest way to explain is to simply link to my code pen.
[Code Pen: CSS3 Expandable Search Form](http://codepen.io/httpJunkie/pen/lEvuy)

I have the same css code applied to two different types of inputs. One is a search input and the other a text input. In order to get similar results from each i have to modify the amount that the transition opens up to in width on the text input and set it to 95% instead of 100%.

My goal was to have each using the same transition code with similar transition effect. But it's not working. I would be very appreciative to anyone who takes a look at it and may be able to help me. Thanks. BTW I am a newbie to both stack overflow and code pen. I'm sorry if I do anything wrong. lol I did try and look for an answer.

I tried posting code here, but I must be doing something wrong. Everything is in code pen though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now have a look at your Code Pen. I have assigned class to every one.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/AlcHr

I hope you wanted to achieve this.

Comment: Yes! Wow, I did't know about the box-sizing & border-box. I figured it was something default in css that was making that text input behave differently. This is the desired function I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your search bar is using a different box model

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Apply that to the rest of your fields and they will behave the same.

Answer (score 0):

The search field has a style applied by the browser of `box-sizing: border-box;`

Apply this to your other fields and they should behave the same.

<kbd>[Updated Pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HapIr)</kbd>

Comment: Nice! I appreciate it!